# Search as you type

Tags: search

Is returning search results while the user is inputting each character good usability practice or a pain in the rear for the user?

Comment: do you mean search results or autocomplete list?! I think showing search results while user is typing has so much overhead for server if you are developing web application.

Comment: Results, your point is valid, however I am not concerned with the overhead and performance, just the usability concept.

Comment: Looks like Google has answered with their Instant Search this week. :)

Comment: It's a pain.  I hate having my results sooner.

Comment: See also this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/is-google-instant-good-or-bad-ux

Comment: There were quite a few complaints about the instant search. I myself have found that I am typing something in, half way through a word, see something interesting but before I can stop typing I have changed the results and I try and go back, deleting letters to try and find the result I am interested in.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From a user's perspective, I've never found it anything but helpful. The search results let me know how I'm most likely to find accurate information for my query and that's never a bad thing. That said, there are a few guidelines to implementing it that should or could be followed.

- Make sure the search form works
  without the AJAX suggestions before
  adding them. Think enhancement to
  what's already there, not
  requirement.
- Never update the search input with
  one of the results unless the user
  requests it.
- Provide keyboard and mouse access for
  selecting results.
- Look-behind is a nice complement to
  look-ahead.

Here's an [Autocompleter](http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/) for MooTools, my favorite JavaScript framework, and ones for [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete), [Dojo](http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/10925_3719341_2/Fun-with-Auto-Complete-Widgets.htm), [Prototype](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/), and [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/).

Comment: This seems to be talking about AutoComplete while the poster seems to be asking about auto-filtering results based on what the user types, without a needing to press a button.

Comment: @Jake - Either way, much of the advice would still stand.

Comment: Can you please explain "Look-behind is a nice complement to look-ahead"?

Comment: Look-ahead compares your query to the beginning of a string while look-behind compares the query to anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with all the others saying "do it", with one exception:

**Make sure it's instantaneous, always, or don't do it!**

There is nothing worse than using an application that does this on, say, the iPhone, and every time you type a character there is a two second delay while the search/filter is performed. This makes it slow and painful instead of quick and helpful, and is a horrible user experience.

I'd say "instantaneous" is in the ballpark of a tenth of a second, maximum, because you should be able to type at normal speed and have the UI keep up.

Comment: Great point. Focus should be on *not blocking input* rather than the search being blazing fast. It's OK for the search to take a few seconds if (a) I can still type more letters and they appear instantly (b) typing more stops current search, starting a new one and (c) there is a UI indicator search is ongoing. Good place for multithreading.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases it's great! Generally it's great because it helps to find something without trying to guess what exactly to type into the search field. And it definitely saves time - one can type one or two letters to find what he is looking for. But of course be sure that the input would not be blocked while the search results are loading. And don't forget about the keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 4):

After typing a search query, there's (logically speaking) only one action that can follow: to hit the search button. Why not eliminate that extra step if it's the only logical next action.

Quote I read somewhere, can't remember by who or where I read it:
"If there's only one thing left to do, have the computer do it."

Comment: How's the case in mobile applications? I mean anyway the user has to click a button to lower the keyboard (the search button and or in android :  the down button that appears instead of back button) otherwise the user can't see a full view of the page and scroll it with ease.

Answer (score 3):

Do it! I can't tell you how many times it has saved me unnecessary trouble because sometimes I forget exactly what I search for and it reminds me just because I remember the first word for what I have been searching for it gives me what I am looking for. Especially because places like Google gives search history.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's great usability in most cases, assuming it doesn't hurt performance:

- It's very natural not know exactly what you're search for, so showing results of a partial input is great.
  Imagine you're looking for an email and you just remember one work of the title.
  The word might be very common and hence return a lot of results. 
  If you see right away, before "submitting" the search, that there are too many, you'll try to type something else to narrow it down immediately.
- Moreover, getting to the result you want is quicker this way.

Answer (score 2):

You should usually prefer direct manipulation over indirect manipulation. That implies tasks are done iteratively with continuous feedback to make the user understand what he or she is doing. Returning results while user is typing is good, because it gives continuous feedback. Likewise property pages should change properties immediately rather than after you hit e.g. and apply button. E.g. selecting a color in a properties panel should immediately change the background color. Rather than it happening after you hit "apply". This helps discoverability of the user interface, because there is a one to one correspondence between what the user does and what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone is getting so very very lazy. Whats wrong with typing in a question like "Where do lions come from" is it so hard to use the keyboard these days. Does everything have to be minimal. TUVM instead of Thank you very much. I know which one I prefer, and its the latter. There is only one place where saving a nano-second is worthwhile and thats in a laboratory, NOT in everyday lives. Does it really matter if your friend can download a program 3 nano-seconds faster than you. My goodness, WOW, what an earth shattering thing to happen. Get a grip folks. I am all for progress but lets not go stupid with it.

Comment: And how exactly does this diatribe answer the question asked?

Comment: And actually, yes, it *is* much harder to use the keyboard these days, especially the virtual kind on small touchscreen devices.

Comment: Most progress is incremental. Search as you type will not change the world, but it is without a doubt an improvement over searching plus enter. There are a lot of people on this site that are enthusiastic about every little user design change, and I suppose you don't share their enthusiasm.